# Scrape a class within a class

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape `class_="href"` with in the `class_="_e4d"`.  Basically looking to scrape a class within a class using BeautifulSoup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver

url = ("https://www.google.com/search?...")

def get_related_search(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\John\\bin\\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
    relate_result = soup.find_all("p", class_="_e4b")
    return relate_result[0]

relate_url = get_related_search(url)
print(relate_url)
```

Results:  markup_type=markup_type))
p class="_e4b"}{a href="/search?...a}{/p}

I now want to scrape the href result. I am not sure what the next step would be.  Thanks for the help.

Note:  I replaced <> with {} since it was not showing up as html script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can actually find this inner `a` element in one go with a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
links = soup.select("p._e4b a[href]")
for link in links:
    print(link['href'])
```

`p._e4b a[href]` would locate all `a` elements having the `href` attribute inside the `p` elements having `_e4b` class.